# fix clazy non-pod-global-static warnings for strings

Tags: c++, static-analysis

Clazy outputs [warnings for non-pod-global-statics](https://github.com/KDE/clazy/blob/master/docs/checks/README-non-pod-global-static.md). I understand why this slows down code, but don't know what a better solution is? For instance, in this simple header file:

module1.hpp

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const std::vector<std::string> namesVec{"name1", "name2", "name3"};
static const std::string name{"name1"};

class Module1
{
  public:
    Module1();
    ~Module1();

    void func1();
};
```

There are two of these warnings, both for `namesVec` and `name`. What's the best way to avoid these warnings?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why these strings can't be just plain, garden-variety, `const char *namesVec[]` and `const char name[]`. Maybe even `const char namesVec[][8]` (or something along those lines), if I want to show off some holier-than-thou programming tricks.

Comment: They can be but `std::string` has nifty functions

Comment: `std::string_view` has the same nifty functions, and is trivially constructible from a `const char *`.

Comment: I see, so is having `const std::string` defined in header files just generally a bad idea?

Comment: You tell me: does defining a relatively complicated class, like `std::string` as a `const` object makes sense when more than half of its method are completely unusable, because it's `const`?

Comment: hmm I see your point and what happens if we had a non-const `std::string` (assuming there's a specific reason for having a non-const global), is it still bad practice to have a non-POD global?

Comment: "Bad practice" is entirely opinion-based. If you ask ten C++ developers whether something is bad practice you'll get eleven different answers. In all cases, you need to make decisions yourself, by understanding what something either does, or does not, and drawing the appropriate conclusions yourself.

Comment: I can change these to `std::string_view` but then I use them in several calls to another API that takes in a `std::string` so at that point I have to convert anyway. Would it still be beneficial to start off w `std::string_view`?

Comment: What does "beneficial" mean, here. Same thing: ask ten C++ developers if *X* is beneficial, get eleven answers in return.

Comment: Beneficial -- Improve performance/increase readability/ reduc possibility of bugs idk -- I'm just trying to understand how seriously I should take the clang warning

Comment: What's perfectly readable to me is going to be complete gobbledygook to someone else. And vice versa. If you would like to understand how seriously you should take that warning, then you need to understand what the warning is about, what is the underlying issue, how it works, and what problems it might create, if at all. There is no central authority somewhere that judges whether a given compiler warning should be paid heed to, or not.